# Does Polymer.js support inner SVG elements?

Tags: svg, polymer

I see examples of using SVG elements within a custom element (such as [here](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/04/building-reusable-d3-js-elements-polymer/)), but so far I haven't been able to figure out how to define a custom element to go *inside* an SVG element.

I've tried the following, and while the template content does appear in the web inspector, the circle doesn't appear visually.

```
<polymer-element name=my-element noscript>
  <template>
    <circle cx=10 cy=10 r=5 />
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<svg>
    <my-element />
</svg>
```

Is there a trick to getting custom elements to work within SVG elements?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this. Elements within the SVG namespace need to be within `<svg>`. Creating `<my-element>` creates a custom element that inherits from `HTMLElement`.

You can however, include `<svg>` in a custom element: http://jsbin.com/EXOWUFu/2/edit

Also, don't forget that custom elements cannot be self closing. So in your example, `<my-element />` -> `<my-element></<my-element>`. This is because the HTML spec only allows a few elements to be self-closing.

**Update**

Turns out you can embed a custom element inside `<svg>` using `<foreignObject>`.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/hareyowi/1/edit

```
<foreignObject width="100" height="100">
  <x-foo></x-foo>
</foreignObject>
```

Comment: So just to be clear: Polymer/Web Components can't be used to create inline SVG trees? At all?

Comment: My example creates an svg tree dynamically using Polymer. What you can't do is inline HTML in SVG like you're doing. That's generally true and has nothing to do with web components.

Comment: It would be great if polymer supported this somehow.

Comment: See my update. `<foreignObject>` is hacky, but works

Comment: About the update: That's *still* not what most people would expect. The example is technically 4 different SVG documents laid out on top of one another. The truth is that Web Components, and subsequently Polymer, don't work fully with other namespaces just yet.

Comment: @BenLesh You said it doesn't work just yet, how do you know that. If its on the roadmap when will it start working.

Comment: I know they don't work because the `<content/>` tag is in a different namespace than SVG. So a template like `<svg><text><content/></text></svg>` will simply not work, because `<content/>` will be an `SVGElement` not an `HTMLContextElement`. It's one of many reasons why Web Components don't work well with SVG.

Comment: @BenLesh I was more keen on not yet part. Is there any work in progress.

Comment: I honestly don't know. Considering the number of issues SVG faces when trying to use Web Components, namespaces issues, createShadowRoot existing but throwing errors, problems registering elements that inherit from SVGElement, etc. ... I'd be really surprised if it works as of this comment, or if it's even being worked on.

Comment: @BenLesh Hey the fix is in for canary and is awaiting stable release. The reported bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=416217

Answer (score 9):

The Polymer FAQ shows that a template can be used within an `<svg>` element:

```
<svg>
    <template repeat="{{l in lights}}">
        <circle cx="100" cy="{{l.cy}}" r="50" fill="{{l.color}}"/>
    </template>
</svg>
```

https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/faq.html#templateinsvg

**Indeed this works in Polymer 0.5!**
But it does **not** work in Polymer 0.9 or 1.0.

In changed Polymer 1.0 syntax it looks like this:

```
<svg>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{lights}}">
        <circle cx="100" cy$="{{item.cy}}" r="50" fill$="{{item.color}}"/>
    </template>
</svg>
```

The element is not rendered and the browser console shows:

```
TypeError: node is undefined   in polymer.html:28
```

The error refers to Polymer's `_parseNodeAnnotations()` function.

That the FAQ example works in 0.5 apparently shows there is no reason why SVG should not work in Web Components or Polymer in principle. This let me hope the Polymer team will fix that soon.

Comment: `<template>` inside SVG will not work on Polymer 1.0 and its a open bug https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1976

Answer (score 2):

According to this open ticket (https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1976), you actually CAN have a template element nested inside an svg element. The fix I will link to below is a port of the code from 0.5. The issue is described in detail here and in the open ticket, so no need to go over it again.

**Important:**

If you would like to indicate to Google and the polymer team that this is indeed an important feature, please make sure you leave a comment on the ticket.

- It does give the intended functionality back in polymer 1.0.
- It is required to be included at the top of the .js file of each web component which may use it.
- It also assumes a specific html structure (which you will see below).
- It only works in chrome right now.

Snippet: https://gist.github.com/bendavis78/15528ca2f501c44f2fa4

**foo-svg.css**

```
foo-svg svg {
    border: 2px solid yellowgreen;
    fill: transparent;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

**foo-svg.html**

```
<dom-module id="foo-svg">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo-svg.css"/>

<template>
    <svg class="clock" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{positions}}" as="cx">
            <circle cx$="{{cx}}" cy="25" r="25" stroke="black" />
        </template>
    </svg>
</template>
<script src="foo-svg.js"></script>
```

**foo-svg.js**

```
(function () {
  // START HACK
  var doc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
  var root = doc.querySelector('dom-module > template').content;
  var templates = root.querySelectorAll('svg template');
  var el, template, attribs, attrib, count, child, content;
  for (var i=0; i<templates.length; i++) {
    el = templates[i];
    template = el.ownerDocument.createElement('template');
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(template, el);
    attribs = el.attributes;
    count = attribs.length;
    while (count-- > 0) {
      attrib = attribs[count];
      template.setAttribute(attrib.name, attrib.value);
      el.removeAttribute(attrib.name);
    }
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    content = template.content;
    while ((child = el.firstChild)) {
      content.appendChild(child);
    }
  }
  // END HACK

  Polymer({
    is: 'foo-svg',

    properties: {
      paths: {
        type: Array,
        value: []
      }
    },

    ready () {
      this.positions = [0, 100, 200, 300];
    }
  });
})();
```