# using svg child tags in content of custom polymer element's template's svg tag

Tags: html, svg, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have the following in my page:

```
<tag-graph id="graph">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20"></circle>
</tag-graph>
```

and the following custom element in another file

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<!-- template possibly for graph visualization using svg -->
<polymer-element name="tag-graph">
  <template>
    <style></style>
    <svg>
      <content></content>
    </svg>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="tag-graph.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Whenever I try to run it in the Dart Editor I get a `ReferenceError` from Polymer.js.

As removing the `<svg>` tags and replacing the `<circle>` tags with raw text results in the expected execution (i.e. I'm pretty sure my scripts and html files are linked up properly [although the text never makes it *into* where the content tag is]), I suspect this has to do with me trying to be too silly with `svg` elements, but I'm frankly quite new to this stuff so I have no idea.

**EDIT**

I think I just broke my run configurations in Dart Editor. I'll look more into it and see what went wrong.

**EDIT EDIT**

Upon fixing that, I no longer get the `ReferenceError` (stupid stuff happened), but I still don't see the circle in the custom element. Furthermore, I can verify that the following, in contrast to the above, behaves as expected:

```
<tag-graph id="graph">
  <svg><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20"></circle></svg>
</tag-graph>
```

and

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<!-- template possibly for graph visualization using svg -->
<polymer-element name="tag-graph">
  <template>
    <style></style>
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="tag-graph.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Also I have no idea how to word the question so if you've got a better way of wording it, go ahead and edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393760/does-polymer-js-support-inner-svg-elements

Comment: I'm doubtful it's a duplicate; the relationship between container and element is reversed with respect to the custom element in my question (although I can upon reading that question now note that 'foreignObject' does not change my error).