# Do Custom Elements / WebComponents work with SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, polymer, web-component

For CustomElements I can do this:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {}
```

Can I do the same for SVG Elements? like

```
class MyOwnRectangle extends SVGRectElement {}
```

If it works, can I trouble someone for a jsbin?

If not, why not?

This has some very good use cases like being able to store **model** data in the element itself. SVG *manipulation* is basically used in 2 major areas:

1. Animations
2. Diagrams like ER, Organisation Charts, Process flows etc.

A library like [JointJS](http://jointjs.com/) has its own abstractions in the form of classes (which extends a Backbone View) to store *model* data associated with the *view* (SVG diagrams on screen).

Like WebComponents can eventually replace jQuery Plugins, Framework X's components in a standard way, why not do the same for SVG?

***Finally***,

**How is Polymer 0.5 able to do this?**

[Does Polymer.js support inner SVG elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393760/does-polymer-js-support-inner-svg-elements)

**How is this patch able to do this in Polymer 1.0?**

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/pull/3372

**What is the alternative for now?**

I guess we can extend `HTMLElement`. In our ShadowDOM use an `<svg>` element and then attach all the SVG tags we actually want to extend like `<rect>`, `<polyline>` etc! Perhaps a much cleaner way out of this?

**Will this be implemented in the future?**

Comment: You alternative is a good solution.

Comment: @Supersharp For cases like generating ER Diagrams, Flow charts etc its not really that good. The outer `<svg>` makes our custom components a big rectangle. Whereas extending something like a `<polyline>` should mean our events etc should fire only when we click on the line not on the boundingbox (outer `svg` element) of the polyline. A lot of DOM APIs fail like `document.elementFromPoint()` etc.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [specification](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#dom-elements)

> If result’s namespace is not the HTML namespace, then throw a NotSupportedError.

All SVG elements are in the SVG namespace. So the specification precludes support.

Ways to store data in SVG include the [the <metadata> tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/metadata.html#MetadataElement) and [data- attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How does Polymer 0.5 and the patch I linked seem to work? Are they bypassing the spec somehow? Also data attrs are available to HTML elements too. But there was a case for custom elements. Why not in SVG?

Comment: I don't see any connection between polymer's patch and web components. If you want to know why something is the way it is in a w3c spec, go ask the w3c.

Comment: My question is 2 fold. Yes I asked about the spec but also of workarounds

Comment: I provided both, the final sentence is about alternatives.

Comment: Metadata seems good but a more powerful solution would be better. If you see the way joint js operates. Its very similar to custom elements. They have their own classes with properties , templated markup and methods. They crrate classes like `erdRect` etc. Which then implement `<rect>` in their markup. But the thing is it doesn't play well with other frameworks, completely ignores all the DOM methods already in an SVG element like `appendChild` etc I was hoping for a solution which can be used like Polymer for SVG. I'll edit my question to be clearer for intent! Thanks again for your answer :)

Comment: Be careful not to invalidate my answer if you edit the question. You can always ask a new question.